# How do I rewrite on client side a svg file I fetched from the server?

Tags: html, reactjs, svg

### Background:

I running an express server with a route to all my static files.

In the static files, I have a folder full of map `.svg`'s.

On the client side (React), I fetch the maps and adding them to to a component.

### Question:

I need to rewrite the `.svg`'s, and add this to their path attribute: `fill=url(#some_flag)`.

#### Svg before:

```
<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 width="1024pt" height="1024pt" viewBox="0 0 1024 1024"
 preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
    <g transform="translate(0,1024) scale(0.1,-0.1)"
        fill="#000000" stroke="none">
        <path d="... numbers...-78 -28 -115 "/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

#### Svg After:

```
<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 width="1024pt" height="1024pt" viewBox="0 0 1024 1024"
 preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
    <g transform="translate(0,1024) scale(0.1,-0.1)"
        fill="#000000" stroke="none">
        <path d="... numbers...-78 -28 -115"
         fill="url(#some_flag)"/>  <!--THE ADDED ATTRIBUTE -->
    </g>
</svg>
```

#### I had a few directions in mind:

1. **Pure Javascript**: `setAttribute` of `path`, which means I'll have to give each path an id?
2. somehow penetrate the `.svg` with CSS? *I tried it and its impossible to override inline SVG attributes*

Have you dealt with it before (of course you did...)? What are my options?

Comment: You can get elements in the DOM even without IDs

Comment: Who said you cant :) ?
I just thought out loud about what would be the best practice for this.

Of course you can target almost anything inside the DOM.
but its better to keep it simple, clean and robust.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering this part: << *I had a few directions in mind:
   1- Pure Javascript: setAttribute of path, which means I'll have to give each path an id?* >>.

It can be the best solution, but I wouldn't use "*id*" because it is not reliable enough (no unicity guaranty, if inadvertently duplicated).
You want to add an attribute *fill*=*"url(#some_flag)"*, and your *#some_flag* is probably indexed somewhere (*flag[i]*), and linkable to the sequence of *path*. If *#some_flag* must be computed from the geometry, you may pre-process it into an array, or compute at run-time. The CSS selector can be more complex also, depending on your needs. This may answer that part of your question:

```
document.querySelectorAll("g > path")
.forEach((x,i) => x.setAttribute("fill",`url(${flag[i]})`));
```

Actually I did experiment it with a svg map excerpted from The Economist Big Mac Index (a local copy):

```
fetch("./bigMacSvg1.txt", {method:"GET"})
.then(res => res.text())
.then(res => {
    //console.log(res);
    document.querySelector(".here").innerHTML = res; //div for svg
    document.querySelectorAll("path:nth-child(n+2)")
    .forEach(x => x.setAttribute("fill","#a1b2c3"));
})
.catch(err => {console.log(err)});
```

The above code sets a light color to every country, but not to the ocean (first path).

Answer (score 1):

As I think you've discovered, including SVG's via an img tag is limiting. Avoid it.

You can set up a sort of proxy component that fetches the SVG contents, converts them to JSX, and lets you include the SVG contents inline. This will allow them to be easily manipulated with CSS and JavaScript.

Here's a library that will handle translating the files to JSX format.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/svg-to-jsx

Comment: In the end, I decided to do this SVG manipulation on the server side, so I didn't have the chance to try it yet, but I'm sure it will be useful one day :)

Comment: @ueeieiie   Actually, that's what we do. I think it's a good call.

Comment: you mean manipulating on the server side?
are you doing it with nodejs?

Comment: @ueeieiie, we are not at that point yet. Currently, just creating JSX  based on a few SVG's as input, basically by hand. You'll probably need to do more than we've done.

Comment: Hey, about `svg-to-jsx`,

How do you import a SVG file into it ?
all of the examples they show are when:
`svg = '<svg>...string string string..</svg>'`.

I'm trying to `import` an SVG file into my component  and to pass it to the `svgtojs(importedSVG)`, but the result I get is empty,

am I missing a step here?